# stm32g030 UART in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, stm32, uart

I am trying to configure **stm32g030** (SOP8) to using UART.
Below you can see the assembly code I have written until now.

Added LED is blinking, so the loop is working.
GDB shows correct values in registers.
But logic analyzer shows nothing, no data at all.
Pin is always HIGH.

@    Registers  values

```
RCC_IOPENR = 0x00000003       @ GPIOA(UART) and GPIOB(LED)
RCC_APBENR2 = 0x00004000  
GPIOA_AFRH = 0x00000010  
GPIOA_MODER = 0xebfbffff  
USART_BRR = 0x00000683  
USART_CR1 = 0x00000009  
USART_CR2 = 0x00000000  
USART_CR3 = 0x00000000  
USART_ISR = 0x002000c0
```

@ 30 seconds from logic analyzer
Chanel1 - blinking LED
Stm32 TX - should be row of 'A'

[image]

**What am I doing wrong? Any help please!**

```
.syntax unified
.cpu cortex-m0plus
.thumb

.word _StackEnd                 @       0x20000100
.word Reset_Handler             @       0x00000004
.space 0xb4  


.equ RCC, (0x40021000)
.equ RCC_IOPENR, (RCC + (0x34))
.equ RCC_APBENR2, (RCC + (0x40))        

.equ SYSCFG, (0x40010000)
.equ SYSCFG_CFGR1, (SYSCFG + (0x00))

.equ GPIOB, (0x50000400)
.equ GPIOB_MODER, (GPIOB + (0x00))
.equ GPIOB_BSRR, (GPIOB + (0x18))

.equ GPIOA, (0x50000000)                
.equ GPIOA_MODER, (GPIOA + (0x00))      
.equ GPIOA_AFRH, (GPIOA + (0x24))       

.equ USART1, (0x40013800)
.equ USART_CR1, (USART1 + (0x00))       
.equ USART_CR2, (USART1 + (0x04))       
.equ USART_CR3, (USART1 + (0x08))       
.equ USART_BRR, (USART1 + (0x0c))       
.equ USART_TDR, (USART1 + (0x28))       
.equ USART_ISR, (USART1 + (0x1c))
```

@       UART config

```
.text
.type Reset_Handler, %function
    Reset_Handler:

    ldr     r0, =RCC_IOPENR         @       (0x40021034)
    ldr     r2, [r0]                
    movs    r3, #0x1                @       0x1 for GPIOA (UART1)
    orrs    r2, r2, r3              
    str     r2, [r0]                

    ldr     r0, =RCC_APBENR2        @       (0x40021040) UART clock enable
    ldr     r2, [r0]                
    ldr     r3, =#0x4001            @   
    orrs    r2, r2, r3              
    str     r2, [r0]                

    ldr     r0, =SYSCFG_CFGR1       @       (0x40010000)
    ldr     r2, [r0]
    movs    r3, #0x8
    orrs    r2, r2, r3
    str     r2, [r0]

    ldr     r0, =GPIOA_AFRH         @       (0x50000024)
    ldr     r2, [r0]                
    ldr     r3, =#0x10              @       define alternate AF1 for PA9 0x10
    orrs    r2, r2, r3              
    str     r2, [r0]

    ldr     r0, =GPIOA_MODER        @       (0x50000000)
    ldr     r2, [r0]                
    ldr     r3, =#0xfffbffff        @   turn on alternate for PA9       
    ands    r2, r2, r3              
    str     r2, [r0]

    ldr     r0, =USART_CR1          @       (0x40013800),
    movs    r3, #0x0                @
    str     r3, [r0]

    ldr     r0, =USART_BRR          @       (0x4001380c)
    ldr     r3, =#0x683             @       16Mhz and 9600
    str     r3, [r0]

    ldr     r0, =USART_CR2          @       (0x40013804),
    movs    r3, #0x0                @
    str     r3, [r0]

    ldr     r0, =USART_CR3          @   (0x40013808),
    movs    r3, #0x0                @
    str     r3, [r0]

    ldr     r0, =USART_CR1          @       (0x40013800),
    ldr     r2, [r0]
    movs    r3, #0x1               @       usart enabled
    orrs    r2, r2, r3
    str     r2, [r0]

    ldr     r0, =USART_CR1          @       (0x40013800)
    ldr     r2, [r0]
    movs    r3, #0x8               @       transmiter enabled
    orrs    r2, r2, r3
    str     r2, [r0]
                              
teack_check:
    ldr     r0, =USART_ISR          @       (0x4001381c)
    ldr     r2, [r0]
    ldr     r3, =#0x200000          @       waiting for TEACK
    tst     r2, r3
    beq     teack_check
```

@   END of UART config

@   GPIOB for LED

```
    ldr     r0, =RCC_IOPENR         @       (0x40021034)
    ldr     r2, [r0]                
    movs    r3, #0x2               @    0x2 for GPIOB (LED)
    orrs    r2, r2, r3              
    str     r2, [r0]                

    ldr     r1, =GPIOB_MODER        @       (0x50000400)
    ldr     r4, [r1]                       
    ldr     r6, =#0xffff7fff        @       0xffff7fff for PB7 
    ands    r4, r4, r6              
    str     r4, [r1]                

blink_loop:

     txe_check:                             
             ldr     r1, =USART_ISR          @   (0x4001381c)
             ldr     r2, [r1]
             ldr     r3, =#0x80
             tst     r2, r3
             beq     txe_check

             ldr     r1, =USART_TDR          @       (0x40013828)
             movs    r3, #0x41              
             uxtb    r4, r3
             str     r4, [r1]

     tc_check:                              
             ldr     r1, =USART_ISR          @       (0x4001381c)
             ldr     r2, [r1]
             ldr     r3, =#0x40
             tst     r2, r3
             beq     tc_check


        ldr     r0, =GPIOB_BSRR         @   0x50000418
        ldr     r1, =#0x80          @   LED turn on
        str     r1, [r0]

        ldr     r2, =#10000000
    wait_1:
        subs    r2, #1
        bne     wait_1

        ldr     r1, =#0x800000          @   LED turn off
        str     r1, [r0]

        ldr     r2, =#10000000
    wait_2:
        subs    r2, #1
        bne     wait_2

        b       blink_loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Pin 5 is PA11 by default; for PA9 you have to set SYSCFG_CFGR1.PA11_RMP.

Btw. don't forget to enable SYSCFG clock in RCC.